# Fetch an entire Entity Group with a single query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Right now I have a "Profile" entity with some child entities like ProfileItem and ProfileAttribute, but this leads to multiple ancestor queries to fetch them. 
Is it possible to fetch this entire Entity Group with a single query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a kindless ancestor query:

```
query = db.Query()
query.ancestor(profile_key)
```